When I kill an app from task manager, it reopens itself a few seconds later
I noticed in my task manager that the Steam Client Webhelper was running, though I had not opened it.  I clicked "End Task" to kill it.  A few seconds later, it restarts!  No matter how many times I kill it, it keeps coming back!
How can I force a program to end and not restart?

Steam Client WebHelper is a browser. It is being called by Steam Client Service, SteamService.exe. A service, AKA daemon in other operating systems, is a task that can be set to run automatically under certain conditions, e.g., at booting, and a service can be set to restart itself or other tasks if stopped.
To prevent Steam Client WebHelper from running at all, you could stop the Steam Client Service from the Services CPL. However, if there is no issue that it causes, and you want to play games using Steam, then ignore it.
If Steam Client WebHelper causes issues, such as high CPU usage, there are things to make it less demanding of resources:

Disable animated avatars.
Disable the Steam overlay... which will also disable some Steam features.
Run Steam without Steam Client WebHelper as follows:

Use Task Manager to kill Steam Client WebHelper and all related processes.
Press WindowsR, paste "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist into the edit, and press Enter. Change that command to suit your installation, if Steam is not in that location.




Steam is rather relentless in keeping itself running on startup. The webhelper process will be running any time the Steam client is running. The only way I have seen to stop it from spawning the webhelper process is to right click the Steam icon in the systray and exit the Steam Client. In Steam settings there should be an option to disable Steam from starting with the system.

Steam Client Service is a Windows Service that calls Steam Client WebHelper. A service can restart an app or itself if killed.

I disabled the Steam Client Service, and the webhelper still continued to spawn when the Steam Client was running. On my system it only went away when I closed the Steam Client.

See the step-by-step answer above.
